# Pass value to controller from link name Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of names, that contain this:

```
<td><%= product.date %></td>
```

and it is in my index page. (It is the list of my applications)

I want to assign a custom link to that, and pass THAT value to the controller:
I tried this:

```
<td><%= link_to product.date, {:controller => "product", :action => "sort_by_date", <how do I pass the 'product.date' string?>  }%></td>
```

I read the rails route guide but I couldn't find help

Thanks

what rakes routes returns:

```
    products GET    /products(.:format)          products#index
                 POST   /products(.:format)          products#create
 new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)      products#new
edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format) products#edit
     product GET    /products/:id(.:format)      products#show
                 PUT    /products/:id(.:format)      products#update
                 DELETE /products/:id(.:format)      products#destroy
            root        /    

                        products#home.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use like below

```
<%= link_to product.date, {:controller => "product", :action => "sort_by_date", :product_date => product.date %>
```

and in your controller you should get the date in `params[:product_date]`

You can also use resource helper function to pass custom parameters like below.

```
<%= link_to product.date, products_path(:product_date => product.date)
```

This method will route to the `ProductsController#index` with a `params[:product_date]`

---

**Edit:**

I just tried with following

```
resources :products do
 collection do
    get 'sort_by_date' => 'products#sort_by_date'
 end
end
```

The rake routes are as following

```
sort_by_date_products GET    /products/sort_by_date(.:format)   products#sort_by_date
```

To generate the URL it will be better to use the resource helper function like below

```
sort_by_date_products_path(:product_date => '1/1/2012')
```

This will generate a url like `/product/sort_by_date?product_date=1/1/2012` which will call the `sort_by_date` method of `ProductsController` and also have `params[:product_date]` available.

Lets check if its work...

Comment: hey thanks! The thing is that I am getting this! No route matches {:controller=>"product", :action=>"sort_by_date", :product_date=>"19/04/2012"}

Comment: I know that I need to add something to my routes file

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would like to try the first way, but I am trying to write the custom route down

Comment: for a quick peak you can try with this `http://railscasts.com/episodes/70-custom-routes` OR `http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/07/17/creating-custom-rails-routes/` 

I will be back soon... Let me know if the above fixed the problem.

Comment: can you please post your related routes?

Comment: I have edited my question, will all my rake routes. The thing is that I don't know the format of the link that '<%= link_to product.date, {:controller => "product", :action => "sort_by_date", :product_date => product.date %>' will return, so I don't know what kind of route to write down in my routes.rb